# Set up a JNDI connection to handle SSL with verify-ca on GeoServer with bundled Jetty

Tags: postgis, geoserver, jetty

I manage a GeoServer connected to PostGIS hosted on Google CloudSQL that must have SSL connections turned on. Since I cannot add client certificates to the native PostGIS connection on GeoServer, I found that this could be done using JNDI. Found some examples of creating and configuring a JNDI data source on Tomcat but nothing about Jetty bundled on GeoServer package.

Has anyone managed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The Jetty package bundled with GeoServer is meant for ease of testing, it's a stripped-down version of Jetty with limited capabilities. For production, use Tomcat instead.